# Zookeeper f-sync issue resulting in Kafka timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are trying to do a single node installation on a VM with 16 cores & 16 GB RAM for Zookeeper & Kafka. Zookeeper is showing f-sync issue and after the set timeout period of 6000ms kafka gives a timeout.

Additional Info:
Zookeeper Version:3.4.6-1569965
Kafka Version:2.11-0.9.0.1

Below entries were there in ZK logs:

```
[2017-03-06 16:37:18,013] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15aa58d60530000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-03-06 16:37:45,308] WARN fsync-ing the write ahead log in SyncThread:0 took 35773ms which will adversely effect operation latency. See the ZooKeeper troubleshooting guide (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)
[2017-03-06 16:37:45,334] INFO Established session 0x15aa58d60530000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:44860 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-06 16:37:45,340] WARN caught end of stream exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15aa58d60530000, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-03-06 16:37:45,347] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:44860 which had sessionid 0x15aa58d60530000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2017-03-06 16:37:50,360] WARN fsync-ing the write ahead log in SyncThread:0 took 5009ms which will adversely effect operation latency. See the ZooKeeper troubleshooting guide (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)
```

Kafka has timeout to ZK errors:

```
[2017-03-06 16:10:11,115] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1223)
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:155)
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:129)
                at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:89)
                at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:71)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:278)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:168)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
                at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
                at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-03-06 16:10:11,120] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-03-06 16:10:11,128] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-03-06 16:10:11,129] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1223)
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:155)
                at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:129)
                at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:89)
                at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:71)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:278)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:168)
                at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
                at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
                at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-03-06 16:10:11,140] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

If this is known issue with any available workaround kindly share any links/forums where I can follow it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your zookeeper is running

You have given correct port in configurations

For Consumer use zookeeper port(2181 default) and for Producer use kafka port(6667 default)